# SmartTarget content not working for multiple region

Tags: 2013-sp1, dd4t, smarttarget

I have a promotion where I have selected multiple regions. It all works fine when there is a single region in the promotion, but if I add another region smart target stop working for this.
I am using Tridion 2013 SP1 with DD4T 2.0 (Java). 
The scenario is I have attached 2 different products in my newly created page, Now I have also created 2 regions for that.

Regions are as below -

```
Product Promo Left
Product Promo Right
```

The problem is If I create a single Promotion using both the regions,then the changes are not reflecting on the site. I have tried to debug and found in this case our query server is not returning any value.

But if I break this into two separate promotion then, It starts reflecting on my site.

Please suggest how to get this working ?

Comment: I can't give you any suggestions, as you haven't given enough information to work from. How exactly does it "stop working"? What have you tried? Have you checked if it is simply a matter of priorities (there are other Promotions with higher priority triggering in that region)? And so on. As much information as you can think of, since we're basically trying to troubleshoot by proxy :)

Comment: Hi @PeterKjaer thanks for the response. I have added more information in to it. Please check it once and let me know if you need any further information regarding this.

Comment: Could you check the SmartTarget log files to see if both of your regions make it into the Fredhopper query? It could be a problem with the DD4T implementation...